# Auto-unindentation

Tags: feature-request

Can code blocks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                                            console.log('hi');
                                                        }
                                                        console.log('done');
```

Be converted to this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('hi');
}
console.log('done');
```

There are 60 spaces on line 2, 56 spaces on line 3, and 56 spaces on line 4. First line isn't counted. So subtract the minimum (56) spaces from every non-first line.

Of course, only do it if there are at least n lines, 8 or more spaces to unindent, and if it makes sense for the language (found from tags).

Comment: Messing with code like this is not a good idea.

Comment: @Wesley So make error-prone humans do it?

Comment: @bjb568: Yes. Any human editing the post presumably knows the language in question and whether it is safe to dedent it or not.

Comment: It's error prone either way.

Comment: @icktoofay You need to spend more time in the edit queue repeatedly pressing "invalid edit".

Comment: @Wesley Yup, so which would have less errors?

Comment: @bjb568: Only if people are dedenting code left and right without discretion. If that were a problem, it probably would have already shown up. Maybe it even has, but I haven’t seen it. Other problems in edits are much more common.

Comment: @bjb568: No, let's not let error-prone humans do it. We should let less knowledgeable and syntax-aware automation do it instead. You need to spend more time in the "let software do things it's not quite cognitive enough to do because people are lazy" queue. :-)

Comment: 9 times out of 10 code like that is attached to a crappy question anyways.

Comment: @icktoofay They aren't doing it to everything, they're just doing it wrongly to half the things. Humans aren't reliable.

Comment: @Ken But… shiney bots! Shiny bots! Does syntax really matter? It's whitespace.

Comment: I really doubt you can automate this anyways. It's too complicated.

Comment: @Wesley Correlation does not mean causation. If I *could* just not unindent my code, I would. That doesn't make my question quality go down.

Comment: @Wesley Do you have a specific case that would pass the test of n lines, 8 spaces, correct tags?

Comment: @bjb568: In some languages, yes. :-) Whitespace can be significant. Python immediately springs to mind as a language where whitespace matters.

Comment: Also in languages where brackets are not always needed (I know of PHP, javascript). You'd have to pretty much write a full blown parser. It's going to be such a mess. And what if the problem is the indentation itself in those cases? Would ruin the point of the question. I'm not down with the idea although I see how it could be nice to have, if it worked correctly.

Comment: If a bunch of languages are a problem, make a whitelist, not a blacklist. If no brackets are needed, the n lines rule would save it.

Answer (score 4):

No, not automatically, and *definitely* not in some tags.

Say someone posted a Python question with this code:

```py
def reverse_string(s):
    return s[::-1]
```

All subsequent lines are indented past the first line, fitting the first criterion. But clearly to people that know Python, that breaks the code: Python is indentation-sensitive. The “at least *n* lines” criterion is also insufficient; you could have a class with a lot of methods, say, and then it’d still be auto-dedented.

Even in tags which generally would be safe to dedent (say, [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)), there might be some special cases (perhaps `#define`s or prototypes going over multiple lines, although the minimum-line requirement might catch that). And of course if someone is asking about indentation sensitivity (perhaps parsing it in a language that is not indentation-sensitive), we don’t want to wreck their post.

Despite this, I think something workable could come out of this. If we set some reasonable criteria somehow including tags, we could *suggest* dedenting the code if such a pattern is detected, and maybe offer an easy way to fix it at the press of a button. But I don’t think we should be doing it manually.

---

Something that has come up in the comments on the question is [whether it would be more error-prone for a human or an automaton to dedent it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256026/auto-unindentation#comment27925_256026). Frankly, I think a human would be better for this. Stack Overflow has generally refrained from automatically editing someone’s post. Sure, [we trim out greetings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989), but that is a very narrow, defined case. It is difficult to come up with a post for which what it removes would be legitimate.

Instead, we tend to warn users before they post a question when it does not meet certain guidelines, and sometimes offer advice about how to fix it. Offering a way to quickly fix the problem, but not force the fix if it is inappropriate, is more in line with the status quo.

It was suggested in the comments that leaving it to humans [leads to the suggested edit queue being filled up with invalid edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256026/auto-unindentation#comment27928_256026). Keeping in mind that the status quo *is* having humans do it, one needs only to look to the edit queue in its current state to judge whether or not it is a good idea. Now, I’m not the most prolific suggested edit reviewer, but from what I’ve seen, there are *plenty* of other kinds of invalid edits that happen; I do not believe I’ve ever seen someone wreck some indentation-sensitive code, much less without having anything else wrong in the edit. As such, I see no harm to leaving it to humans.

Comment: The problem with the edit queue isn't only that it's annoying, it's that they get *approved*.

Comment: @bjb568: Can you point me to an example of where a snippet of code in an indentation-sensitive language was incorrectly dedented by a suggested edit? I probably haven’t spent as much time in the queues as you, but I haven’t seen any.

Comment: Just because I review suggested edits a lot doesn't mean I have magical search powers to search thru my almost-1k reviews… In any case, most people won't bother unindenting (which leaves poor quality on the site), it's approved very fast (so I can't get around to rejecting it), and almost always it's correct (it's not a hard task).

Comment: @bjb568: I might be misinterpreting your comment, but is your main complaint that suggested edits usually don’t touch the indentation in cases where a dedent would be a correct course of action, and that as a result, the suggested edits are unsubstantive/too minor and should be rejected (but are nevertheless accepted)?

Comment: My complaint is a) It's impossible to find examples because *nobody makes that kind of edit* b) They will be approved regardless of whether it's invalid c) It's correct so much that making humans do it is unnecessary as a bot can probably do it better, and far more (see one).